# How can I strip the comma from the last echo in a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I need to strip the comma from the last echoed file. So I need to remover the come from the line `"$aSong['ID'].'.mp3"},"`. On the last one that is echoed

```
while ( $aSong = mysql_fetch_array($sql_get_files) ) {
        //Creates an array of $thisSong[ID], $thisSong[Title], etc.
        // substr removes the first 4 letters of the KEY
        foreach ( $aSong as $sKey => $sValue )
            $thisSong[substr($sKey,4)] = stripslashes($sValue);
        //Ditch $thisSong for the prev value
        $aSong = $thisSong; unset($thisSong);
        $mp3r = '';
        echo '{name:"'.$aSong['Artist'].' '.$aSong['Title'].
             '",mp3:"http://domain.com/uploads/audio/'.$aSong['ID'].'.mp3"},';
}
```

Comment: Is the output supposed to be JSON or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while ( $aSong = mysql_fetch_array($sql_get_files) ) {
        //Creates an array of $thisSong[ID], $thisSong[Title], etc. substr removes the first 4 letters of the KEY
        foreach ( $aSong as $sKey => $sValue ) $thisSong[substr($sKey,4)] = stripslashes($sValue);
        //Ditch $thisSong for the prev value
        $aSong = $thisSong; unset($thisSong);
        $mp3r = '';
        $tmp.= '{"name":"'.$aSong['Artist'].' '.$aSong['Title'].'","mp3":"http://domain.com/uploads/audio/'.$aSong['ID'].'.mp3"},';
}
echo rtrim($tmp,',');
```

You could also just populate an array:

```
$tmp_arr = array();
while ( $aSong = mysql_fetch_array($sql_get_files) ) {
        //Creates an array of $thisSong[ID], $thisSong[Title], etc. substr removes the first 4 letters of the KEY
        foreach ( $aSong as $sKey => $sValue ) $thisSong[substr($sKey,4)] = stripslashes($sValue);
        //Ditch $thisSong for the prev value
        $aSong = $thisSong; unset($thisSong);
        $mp3r = '';
        $tmp_arr[] = '{"name":"'.$aSong['Artist'].' '.$aSong['Title'].'","mp3":"http://domain.com/uploads/audio/'.$aSong['ID'].'.mp3"}';
}
echo implode(',',$tmp_arr);
```

You also need to quote your JSON keys so `{mp3:"http...mp3"}` becomes `{"mp3":"http...mp3"}`. If you're trying to output JSON to the browser for AJAX or whatever, you'll need something like this instead:

```
echo '{"0":[' . implode(',',$tmp_arr) . ']}';
```

Once you have all your output, take it over to [JSONlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com) and validate it.

Comment: Worked to perfection! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use an auxiliary variable to keep track of whether you're at the *first* element or not. If you're *not* at the first element, output a comma *before* the opening brace.

Comment: Hmm that will work but I think it might be overkill to check for the first element in every iteration.

Comment: It's just a Boolean variable that you initialize to `true` and set to `false` at the end of each iteration. That's about the _least_ burdensome thing I can imagine.